# PHP 5:How can I extand a file in a higher directory?

Tags: php, namespaces, extends

first timer here.

I'm writing a script to convert namespaces and class names to meet current standards i.e.:

// original
namespace oldNS;

class foo_bar_baz_someClass extends topLvlFile {

// revised
class someClass extends topLvlFile {

namespace oldNS\foo\bar\baz;

The issue I'm having is extending topLvlFile as it is in a higher directory.
Obviously 'class someClass extends ....\topLvlFile' will fail.

I've been scouring the web trying to find a solution but had little luck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: dont you include the file first then just extend the class as per normal?  Or in fact probably more apropriate to require rather than include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

requiere '../toplvlfile';

Someclass extends SomeOtherClass